# send real time data from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, real-time

I need a way to get data from elasticsearch so that every time a JSON object get submitted into elasticsearch, it can be detected and sent to another process. I've been googling for a while, but I can't find any tools or tutorial to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: These answers might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210383/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-email-alerts-in-elastisearch/34215912#34215912 + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681300/how-to-set-up-percolator-to-return-when-an-aggregation-value-hits-a-certain-thre/39761323#39761323

Answer (score 0):

You are looking [for alerting](https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/alerting).
Look at this [video](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/getting-started-with-alerting-for-elasticsearch) about how to use it