# Notification with Laravel Elasticsearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

We are out of ideas on the proper approach to this scenario.

We have a system, where users can set up some search criteria's and save it, if there are any matches found in the system we will show results.

But we need to set up a cronjob, where if any new matches found (these can be either updated records or new records) then we have to give a count of newly matched records notification icon, on click, on that need to show a list of new matched records to the user who has created the search criteria.

At this moment we are not storing the search results in the database, is there any approach that we can achieve this without saving the matched records to a table.

We are thing that, if we save the results into the database it becomes huge in the very near future.

Sorry for grammatical mistakes, hope I conveyed problem clearly.

May be my problem is very close the stackoverflow inbox alert concept.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210383/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-email-alerts-in-elastisearch/34215912#34215912 (hint: use percolation)

Comment: @Val thanks for the link I will check on it