# Is there any mechanism to send notification for large set of queries if matching item added to table

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, notifications, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a AWS dynamodb table with set of documents and all data will be replicated to elasticsearch cluster using AWS Lambda function. My web site serve feature to search these documents of that dynamodb table using elasticsearch cluster.

My requirement is, a users should be able to subscribe for a search query to get email updates daily or weekly (or instant) of newly added documents which are matching for their query. According to the data set, expected user query amount is around 1,000,000. New documents can be added around 100. (In this case no need to use full-text search. Simple matching is acceptable).

Is there any known technology for fulfilling this requirement? I am currently using nodeJS + AWSLabda + DynamoDB + Elasticsearch and also ready to technology change if required.

Current database details:

```
Entity: Book 
Fields:
    name: string
    price: number
    category: string array
```

I can't run all 1,000,000 queries if new document added to the database. Is there any efficient technology to do that.

Comment: You want to dig into the [percolator field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/percolator.html) which provides exactly that feature. Here is an answer that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215912/4604579

Comment: @Val Thanks for the quick reply. I think this is exactly what I need. I'll dig into this for further information. This can be use for instant notification. Have you any suggestion for summarizing daily and weekly? It is enough to give most matching 5 results in the daily/weekly mail. Thanks a lot

Comment: Aggregate and store the results from the percolator queries yourself, and send them in a daily or weekly email.

Comment: What @Backgammon said... or leverage ElastAlert or XPack Alerting (formerly Watcher) or [Sentinl](https://github.com/sirensolutions/sentinl)